# jQuery: mouse events aren't working

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mydiv').mouseenter(function() {
                $('.mydiv').fadeTo('fast', 1);
            });
            $('.mydiv').mouseleave(function() {
                $('.mydiv').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>


<body>
     <div class="mydiv"><br><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   

</body>
</html>
```

The code above is a test HTML file in which the jQuery isn't working, could anybody help me find a solution to my problem. I can't find the error (I use Google Chrome 34.0.1847.137 m).

If anybody needs, this is the CSS file:

```
div {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for using the old jQuery 1.6.4 ?

Comment: Open the console and tell us the error message ...

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z8YBm/1

Comment: please update your script tag `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @MikeHometchko - That's valid HTML5 code.

Comment: orly?  learn something new everyday I suppose.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e4f7v/ code works fine script tag and another suggestion use latest variants of jquery libs

Comment: What are you expecting to happen vs. what's actually happening?

Comment: @user36 why don't you simply use CSS3 transitions for that fade effect?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What sorry i dint get you

Comment: @user36 "my code is not working" is not a Title and not a question. A question should look like "I have this specific error: bla bla bla, how to bla bla bla". Please edit accordingly.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Am not the Orginal Poster its user3642345

Comment: @Paul Rob the DIV should fade when you entered the mouse and return when you take it off. Nothing is happening.

Comment: The code isn't simply executing in Chrome, but it works in jfiddle

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan but it doesn't show an error, it simply does nothing!

Comment: Pay attention to these comments, please, and react to them.

Comment: did ya change the correct the script tag

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I used this code to test jQuery, but it isn't working.

Comment: Did you check Chrome's console for errors?

Comment: It says "$ is not defined"

Comment: @user3127499 now I'm using the original jQuery.com. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Comment: so now did it start working

Comment: If it's working everywhere but on my browser, I guess it's an error on my machine.

Comment: @bigmike you've could make the title a bit more descriptive while editing it...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I agree and have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of jQuery, change to a newer version and it will work in Chrome.

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ninun/3/edit)**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also just a small edit to your code:

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand
    $('.mydiv').hover(function( e ) {
         $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, e.type=="mouseenter"?1:0.5);
    });
});
```

---

Without jQuery, in CSS3

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ninun/2/edit)**

```
.mydiv{
     /* your styles here */
     opacity: 0.5;
     transition: opacity 0.3s;
 }
 .mydiv:hover{
     opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: Not if he's seeing "$ is not defined" (see the last comment). Also, one of the posted JSFiddle links (and a local test I ran) use the old jQuery version and all still works.

Comment: @user3642345 I've edited my answer with some fixes. Have you tried my link examples? which one is not working?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan They're working. However, the code doesn't work on a HTML file opened in Chrome

Comment: @user3642345 might as well go for Occum's Razor here, is the machine you are running the code on actively connected to the internet when you try to run the page?  If so, are there any network-related restrictions you are aware of?

Comment: @user3642345 try to clear your cache, see what console says, errors? You can also download my jsBin demo's and test test test.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It says $ is not defined

Comment: @MikeHometchko Yes, it's on the same machine I'm using to access this website

Comment: @user3642345 on your document or on my jsBin demos?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It works on the jsBin demos, but not on my doc.

Comment: @user3642345 the error you are receiving means that you are not properly grabbing the jQuery library.  Try a different script source.

Comment: @user3642345 on what line is the error? have you checked all your codes? Can you try to download the jsBin and test it?

Comment: @MikeHometchko Already tried GoogleAPIs, official jQuery.com, do you have any examples?

Comment: @user3642345 you can also create a jQuery .js file and save it, referencing it locally.  That will work without question.  If it doesn't your computer is haunted.

Comment: @user3642345 examples of what? I think you're first calling your <script> and that jQuery... should be inverse, first include jQuery, than create your jQuery functions

Comment: @user3642345 can you paste all your code into a jsBin.com so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it works on jsBin. [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ramasamo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @Funest we know that, and it works also if you download the demo and run locally from `file://`. What's your point?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I guess there's something wrong on my machine. From now on, I'll use jsBin for coding. Thanks.